# htaccess redirect for global subdomains system - all subdomains redirected to one php file to handle them all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i really could use some advices related to subdomains.

recently we decide to make every subdomain of main portal to be available for blogs (something similar to lets say any blog platform)

so what i cant achieve is to make redirection to certain folder of main portal site or php file like:

`xxxxx.domain.com/index.php?get=xx&get2=xx` -> to be run by actual php file located on main portal account, lets say `subdomains.php?get=x&get2=xx`, alternatively - to be run by `mainportal/subdomains/index.php?get=x&get2=xx`

i tried with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) subdomain.php [L]
```

effect was almost correct but get parameters are missing:( 
on the other hand it can be entirely wrong... i simply dont understand or that rewrite rules:(

thanks for any help/tips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `QSA` (query string append):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*\.domain\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule . subdomain.php [QSA]
```

Comment: Just for trivia, I remember QSA meaning "query string *attach*"

Comment: @MihaiStancu :) [read here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags)

Comment: thanks - i think its what i needed, for now its doing what i need:) but to really test it i have to build that mini blog site - anyway big thanks for now

Comment: i have one followup - how to modify it to use files from main domain but using subdomain address: i have xxx.domain.pl and wanna access files using xxx.domains.pl/css/style.css but instead it loads that subdomain.php, i tried adding conditions: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d, but neither of them seems to work